# How to know if UITableViewCell is deselected in editing mode

Tags: ios, uitableview, editing

I have a tableview which supports editing for deletion. Tableview supports multi-selection if it is in edit mode. I want to enable or disable delete button according to the number of cells selected. If at least one cell is selected, I ll enable the delete button otherwise not. Similar to iPhone mail app. 
When I select a cell didSelectRowMethod is called in editing mode and I m enabling the delete button. But if I tap on the selected cell again to deselect, didSelectRow is not called. So I m not able to disable my delete button. Do you have any idea how to know and where to get the control if a cell is deselected in editing mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

here how can check if its in edit mode  dont forget to set `tableview.delegate=self;`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
      if ([tableView isEditing]) {
                 NSLog(@"tableview is editing");      
            }else{
                 NSLog(@"tableview is not editing");   
              }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:
selected
A Boolean value that indicates whether the cell is selected.
@property(nonatomic, getter=isSelected) BOOL selected
Discussion
The selection affects the appearance of labels, image, and background. When the selected state of a cell is set to YES, it draws the background for selected cells with its title in white. The default value is NO. If you set the selection state to YES through this property, the transition to the new state appearance is not animated. For animated selected-state transitions, see the setSelected:animated: (page 26) method.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I found there is a delegate method on UITableview called -

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

In this method deselection can be known.

Answer (score 0):

Please implement **didDeselectRowAt indexPath:**  delegate method when the table is in editing mode as didSelectRowAt will not work in deselecting

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
}